# Update a record with new data based on match

Tags: google-apps-script, replace, google-sheets

I have data in a sheet called WOL that has a unique number in Col A.
In col B of that same sheet I have recorded a Tech name (let's say SAM).
I have an entry in cell H1 of a sheet called WL.
I have an entry in cell B2 of the WL sheet with a new Tech Name (let's say JACK).
I need to match the cell H1 value of WL to the Col A of WOL.
When it finds a match between the value in H1 of WL and the COL A of WOL, I want to write over the existing Tech Name (SAM) in the same row and replace it with JACK.

I'm fairly new to Apps Script but I think I can follow your code if you could help.

My sheet is linked https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E7adi88aEgvdV4ao8unbMHgZLEyu5CCRdTOjv8thjtc/edit#gid=1880893017

Comment: This is not a script writing service: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask It is not unreasonable for us to ask you to put in at least some effort and use the power of the Internet to 1) find similar questions, 2) Review official documentation (which includes samples, guides, and tutorial code!), and 3) attempt to write a function doing what you want.

Comment: To be clear . . I didn't ask the question without 4 hours of research and not finding what I needed.  I have written code for which I kept getting stuck and I deleted the code as I was getting frustrated and confused.  In the future, I will include the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function matchH1() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('WOL');
  var rg1=sh1.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg1.getValues();
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('WL');
  var h1=sh2.getRange('H1').getValue();
  var b2=sh2.getRange('B2').getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][0]==h1) {
     sh1.getRange(i+1,2).setValue(b2);
     ss.toast("Match found. Tech name replaced");
     break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Couple of things.  Link to the sheet is <https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E7adi88aEgvdV4ao8unbMHgZLEyu5CCRdTOjv8thjtc/edit?usp=sharing> .  I should have included that.  Second, it is executing but it's changing the value in Col A when it finds a match.  It should be changing the value in Col B (replace the old tech with the new tech).   Maybe we need an offset?   Last, the script runs for ever and doesn't appear to terminate.  I think we're almost there.

Comment: Okay that should do it.

Comment: Excellent and thank you so much.  The part that I was getting stuck on was the if section.  I'm new to coding and, when I can see the code, I can follow what it's doing.  Just not confident to write it from scratch.  Very helpful and I'm now editing the code to include many kinds of "update" features.